# How to escalate NAGIOS CORE service to alert also without changing the state? (During the CRITICAL-Phase)

Tags: nagios

We have a PowerShell Script comparing AD Groups and alerting if there are any differences.
The services works good. If the state changes (CRITICAL to RECOVERY or vica versa) it is OK.

We would like however that we receive Alerts even though the state did not changed.

NAGIOS CORE should alert as till the the services is recovered.

I have tried to add an escalate command, it does not work however.
I have received one alert as it got "CRITICAL" but anyway nothing happens. We do not receive a 2nd or 3rd alert.

```
define service{
        name                        CheckADGroups_admins
        use                         systemhealth
        service_description         Check AD Admin Groups for Members of Administrators
        check_command               check_by_nrpe!check_domainadmins_admins!-t 300 ;
        check_interval              60                          
        servicegroups               +AVIR                           
        contact_groups              +ADGruppe
        register                    0
}

define serviceescalation{
        host_name                   HOSTNAME
        service_description         Check AD Admin Groups for Members of Administrators
        first_notification          1
        last_notification           0
        notification_interval       10
        contact_groups              +ADGruppe
    }
```

Has somebody an idea how to change the config?

Comment: If you mean that you should *keep* getting notifications as long as the state is CRITICAL, ie not just one, this is controlled by notification_interval on the object (or parent host, if missing on the service). Read more here: https://assets.nagios.com/downloads/nagioscore/docs/nagioscore/3/en/objectdefinitions.html -- remove the service escalation, it's not going to do what you think.

Comment: Thank you very much. I have added the command to the service, it did not send me a 2md alert after 5min.: "notification_interval       5"

Comment: The problem is that a hostgroup has a settting " notification_interval 0"! I cannot change the group without changing it for the entire hostgroup ...

Comment: Incorrect, a host group cannot have attributes. Maybe you're thinking about a template? If so, any value on the object itself will override whatever comes from the template ("use template_name"). I also encourage you to dig into the documentation linked above, and try *removing* unnecessary attributes on the objects, it will make it easier to troubleshoot what is happening. You likely need to manually trace the "chain" of what's being set (template -> object), you can also see current values under config in the Nagios web UI